# Angular ngAnimate list items automatically fade out

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a weird issue with ngAnimate in a simple application I'm doing with the MEAN Stack.

Both *angular.js* and *angular-animate.js* are 1.4.7 version.

I have an *ul* that looks something like this:

```
<ul>
   <li ng-repeat="item in items" class="fade">
      {{item.name}}
   </li>
</ul>
```

In the controller I'm getting the items array with an $http.get() call to the MongoDB.

This is the CSS code for the simple animation:

```
.fade {
  transition: 1s linear all;
  -webkit-transition: 1s linear all;
}

.fade.ng-enter {
  opacity: 0;
}

.fade.ng-enter.ng-enter-active {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

If for example I refresh the page,the controller gets the items array from the Database, and the list items fade in, but they fade out right after the fade in effect.

What is causing this undesired fade effect back to opacity:0 ? Could it be the way the functions I'm using the get the data interact with the view?

Comment: Both angular and angular-animate are 1.4.7 version

Comment: Can you inspect the elements after they have faded out and see where they get their `display: none` or `opacity: 0` from?

Comment: Can you provide us a fiddle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it was a default Bootstrap.css class called '.fade', which has opacity:0 rule;

Overriding that class in my style.css solved the undesired fade out. I hope it helps.